# Sample code or project for Facial Recognition using C#.net without using third party libraries?

Tags: c#

I want sample code for Facial Recognition using C#.net without using third party libraries.
I want to achieve this using microsoft libraries.
I gone through this link "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real-ti" but in that link they have used "Emgu.CV.dll" and some other external OS libraries(DLLs).
I want to know whether these dlls are open source libraries??
How can i achieve this task using microsoft or open source dlls??

Any ideas??
Pls suggest me..

Comment: Microsoft doesn't publish such a library, you'll have to make do with what's available.  Pickings are slim, this is not an attractive target for library vendors that take support phone calls.  OpenCV is the game in town, Emgu is a .NET wrapper for it.  They are open source.  Pretty necessary to debug the crashes your program will suffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) Open Source Computer Vision Library is probably what your're looking for.

Comment: Can i use this OpenCV Library for commercial purpose??

Comment: I am having one more question, it is possible to achieve FaceRecognition in C# without using OpenCV??

Comment: OpenCV is released under a BSD license and hence it’s free for both academic and commercial use. And yes you can do it c# without open cv, but that's not trivial.

Comment: thanks niklas and Hans Passant for your valuable comments...

Comment: On a side note, @Lokesh if you have access to a Kinect device that is probably the by far easiest implementation for the problem in C# using the SDK. But the license model might not be attractive.